# SQL Find and Replace

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress, replace

How can i do the following  :

In my Wordpress website, i want to replace something in the post content

All instances of :
http://play.videolog.tv/videos/xx/xx/yyyyyy.flv

Replace with :
[videolog]yyyyyy[/videolog]

xx can be 2 or 3 digits, but yyyyyy is always 6 numbers.

Example :

http://play.videolog.tv/videos/93/80/398682.flv to [videolog]398682[/videolog]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

```
update MyTable
set MyColumn = concat('[videolog]', replace(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(MyColumn, '/', -1), 2), '.flv', '[/videolog]'))
where MyColumn like 'http://play.videolog.tv/videos/%'
```

Comment: @virendar: I read too quickly and didn't realize the *xx* values were numbers. See my updated version above.

Comment: hello sorry for the late reply, thank you for that! it is almost perfect....instead of getting [videolog]398682[/videolog] I got [videolog]98682[/videolog] (the 3 is missing?)

Comment: ah also, it does not work when the line is in the middle of other text, or if other text is after it, in my post content

Answer (score 0):

It takes some string magic to do this entirely in MySQL.  I believe this should work:

```
UPDATE posts_table
SET posts_table.post_text = REPLACE(posts_table.post_text, @full_url := MID(posts_table.post_text, @url_start := LOCATE('http://play.videolog.tv/videos/', posts_table.post_text), LOCATE('.flv', posts_table.post_text, @url_start) + 4 - @url_start), 
CONCAT('[videolog]', MID(@full_url, LENGTH(@full_url) - LOCATE('/', REVERSE(@full_url)) + 2, 6), '[/videolog]'))
WHERE LOCATE('http://play.videolog.tv/videos/', posts_table.post_text)
```

You can test it with this query:

```
SELECT REPLACE(posts_table.post_text, @full_url := MID(posts_table.post_text, @url_start := LOCATE('http://play.videolog.tv/videos/', posts_table.post_text), LOCATE('.flv', posts_table.post_text, @url_start) + 4 - @url_start), 
CONCAT('[videolog]', MID(@full_url, LENGTH(@full_url) - LOCATE('/', REVERSE(@full_url)) + 2, 6), '[/videolog]')) AS `result`
FROM posts_table
WHERE LOCATE('http://play.videolog.tv/videos/', posts_table.post_text)
```

Just replace posts_table and post_text with the correct table/column names.

This query should replace all instances of that URL, even if it is in the middle of a bunch of text.